# weighted average caluculation in access table

Tags: ms-access

I have a table having tonnes and grade of a commodity. In the end of table, I want to calculate sumor tonnes, that comes easily and weighted average of grade. Caould you please let me know how to calculate weighted average in an access table I can add another column in the table. Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3QJP.png)

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
Select
    Sum(Tonnes) As TotalTonnes,
    Sum(Tonnes * Grade) / Sum(Tonnes) As AverageGrade,
    Sum(Ounces) As TotalOunces
From
    YourTable
```